# Elixir Phoenix - How to create and import javascript files into specific templates

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, assets

I'm currently experimenting with the Elixir Phoenix framework together with Liveview. For my project, I would like to write some Javascript code that is only imported on certain pages (templates). Although this seems like something very trivial, I am struggling to get it working.

At this moment I created a seperate Javascript file as such `assets/js/custom.js`. After doing this, I added the following line to my root.html.heex as a first test to see if this already works. For this line, I simply looked at how `app.js` is imported.

```
<script defer phx-track-static type="text/javascript" src={Routes.static_path(@conn, "/assets/custom.js")}></script>
```

The next step would then be to figure out how to import it in a seperate template instead of the root. However, this first test already failed resulting in the following error:

```
[debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /assets/custom.js (MyAppWeb.Router)
(my_app 0.1.0) lib/phoenix/router.ex:405: MyAppWeb.Router.call/2
(my_app 0.1.0) lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex:1: MyAppWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
(my_app 0.1.0) lib/plug/debugger.ex:136: MyAppWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
(my_app 0.1.0) lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex:1: MyAppWeb.Endpoint.call/2
(phoenix 1.6.15) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:54: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/4
(cowboy 2.9.0) c:/Users/arnod/Desktop/phoenixtut/my_app/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_handler.erl:37: :cowboy_handler.execute/2
(cowboy 2.9.0) c:/Users/arnod/Desktop/phoenixtut/my_app/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:306: :cowboy_stream_h.execute/3
(cowboy 2.9.0) c:/Users/arnod/Desktop/phoenixtut/my_app/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:295: :cowboy_stream_h.request_process/3
(stdlib 4.0.1) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Could somebody help me figure this one out? How does one add seperate Javascript files and only import them in specific templates?

Comment: Never used LiveView, but is there a typo in your path? missing `/js/`?

Comment: From my limited understanding Phoenix (Liveview) copies anything you put under the `assets` folder to the `priv/static/assets` folder. Although it should do that, it does not for my file. I probably missed an important step. When your file is copied to there, I'm thinking that patch should work, just like with `app.js`.

Comment: @Dogbert sharp, but no, phoenix serves static files directly from priv/assets, the static file server knows how to resolve these without those prefixes, you can configure alternate behavior by changing the config files

Answer (score 1):

You can import all your custom javascript once in app.js, assign them as hooks which you can then use in your (live) views, wherever needed, for example;

**custom.js**

```
export const SomeFunction = {
  mounted() {
    alert("some function ran!");
  }
}
```

**app.js** snippet

```
...

import {SomeFunction} from "./custom.js"

let Hooks = {}
Hooks.SomeFunction = SomeFunction

let csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content")
let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {params: {_csrf_token: csrfToken}, hooks: Hooks})

...
```

Then in your live view render function (or template) add the hook

```
...

  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    ...
    
    <div id="my-hook" phx-hook="SomeFunction"></div>
    
    ...
  end

...
```

More about javascript interoperability can be found on the Phoenix hex page [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/js-interop.html). You can tie them to all sorts of phoenix events.

nb. Also note that @conn isn't available in live views, only @socket is.